# Getting error (exit code 2) for bootsnap, not allowing to set up Rails Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, development-environment

Trying to test a website built on Rails and keep getting an error that refuses to allow me to set up my server.

After getting an error, I used 'gem install bootsnap -v '1.4.2' --source 'https://rubygems.org/' with the source as Rubygems. Same error:

```
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing bootsnap:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/ext/bootsnap
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/bin/ruby.exe -I C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0 -r ./siteconf20190327-13232-1084dsi.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/ext/bootsnap
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/ext/bootsnap
make "DESTDIR="
generating bootsnap-i386-mingw32.def
compiling bootsnap.c
bootsnap.c: In function 'bs_cache_path':
bootsnap.c:240:3: warning: unknown conversion type character 'l' in format [-Wformat]
bootsnap.c:240:3: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
bootsnap.c: In function 'bs_rb_fetch':
bootsnap.c:281:3: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Wdeclaration-after-statement]
bootsnap.c: In function 'fetch_cached_data':
bootsnap.c:407:3: warning: comparison is always false due to limited range of data type [-Wtype-limits]
bootsnap.c: In function 'atomic_write_cache_file':
bootsnap.c:479:3: warning: implicit declaration of function 'mkstemp' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
bootsnap.c: In function 'bs_rb_fetch':
bootsnap.c:623:13: warning: 'output_data' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
bootsnap.c:594:9: note: 'output_data' was declared here
linking shared-object bootsnap/bootsnap.so
bootsnap.o: In function `atomic_write_cache_file':
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.3.3\lib\ruby\gems\2.3.0\gems\bootsnap-1.4.2\ext\bootsnap/bootsnap.c:479: undefined reference to `mkstemp'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [bootsnap.so] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.3.0/bootsnap-1.4.2/gem_make.out
```

My gemfile includes this:

```
# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.2', require: true
```

I do see bootsnap located: C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.3.3\lib\ruby\gems\2.3.0\gems

Would anyone know how to get rid of this? It is not located on my *gem list* either.

```
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing bootsnap:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/ext/bootsnap
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/bin/ruby.exe -I C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0 -r ./siteconf20190327-21940-1y9qpk9.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/ext/bootsnap
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2/ext/bootsnap
make "DESTDIR="
generating bootsnap-i386-mingw32.def
compiling bootsnap.c
bootsnap.c: In function 'bs_cache_path':
bootsnap.c:240:3: warning: unknown conversion type character 'l' in format [-Wformat]
bootsnap.c:240:3: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
bootsnap.c: In function 'bs_rb_fetch':
bootsnap.c:281:3: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Wdeclaration-after-statement]
bootsnap.c: In function 'fetch_cached_data':
bootsnap.c:407:3: warning: comparison is always false due to limited range of data type [-Wtype-limits]
bootsnap.c: In function 'atomic_write_cache_file':
bootsnap.c:479:3: warning: implicit declaration of function 'mkstemp' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
bootsnap.c: In function 'bs_rb_fetch':
bootsnap.c:623:13: warning: 'output_data' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
bootsnap.c:594:9: note: 'output_data' was declared here
linking shared-object bootsnap/bootsnap.so
bootsnap.o: In function `atomic_write_cache_file':
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.3.3\lib\ruby\gems\2.3.0\gems\bootsnap-1.4.2\ext\bootsnap/bootsnap.c:479: undefined reference to `mkstemp'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [bootsnap.so] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.2 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.3.0/bootsnap-1.4.2/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and I'm also using railsinstaller on a windows computer.

To solve it, I updated my Gemfile like this :

```
#gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false
gem 'bootsnap', '= 1.4.1', require: false
```

Then run the command : `bundle install` in your project directory.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same problem. I'm using ruby 2.3.0, rails 5.2.3.
To solve it, I updated my Gemfile.

```
# it don't work....
# gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false
# gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.2', require: false

gem 'bootsnap', require: false
```

Then bundle install and it works!