# Problem when installing rails on windows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to create new demo rails program, as guide in my book as this command

`rails new demo`

then it gave me this error

https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4vJk.jpg

It said that my problem is

`Could not find gem sqlite3 <> 1.4 x86-mingw32 in any of the gem sources listed in your Gem file`

and I must run

`bundle install`

to solve it

I ran `bundle install` , but nothing changed.

I know my question maybe too easy to solve, but I am very stuck with this, could you please give me some ideas?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of the bootsnap gem in rails: "This gem works on macOS and Linux." See: https://github.com/Shopify/bootsnap

They seem to have found a workaround here:
[How can I properly install bootsnap on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55857930/how-can-i-properly-install-bootsnap-on-windows)

Add or change to `gem 'bootsnap', '=1.4.1', require: false` to your project Gemfile

Comment: Dear friends, finally I can solve my problem by this link https://medium.com/ruby-on-rails-web-application-development/how-to-install-rubyonrails-on-windows-7-8-10-complete-tutorial-2017-fc95720ee059, just follow him and we can solve it. Good luck!