# How to fix ' Failed to build gem native extension' error with bootsnap with Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows

I am using Windows, and I just installed Ruby on Rails, ruby is version 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [x64-mingw32], rails is version 6.0.0.
When running rails new blog (following [this tutorial](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#installing-rails)) bundle install runs.

I have tried reinstalling Ruby, changing its version, and even removing bootsnap and running something else, but even when trying to install the puma gem I get the same error.

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory:
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/ext/bootsnap
C:/Ruby26-x64/bin/ruby.exe -I C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r
./siteconf20191028-6188-1rw29js.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory:
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/ext/bootsnap
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory:
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/ext/bootsnap
make "DESTDIR="
generating bootsnap-x64-mingw32.def
compiling bootsnap.c
linking shared-object bootsnap/bootsnap.so
C:/Ruby26-x64/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
bootsnap.o:bootsnap.c:(.text+0x557): undefined reference to `__strcat_chk'
C:/Ruby26-x64/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
bootsnap.o:bootsnap.c:(.text+0xa07): undefined reference to `__chk_fail'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:261: bootsnap.so] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5 for inspection.
Results logged to
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.6.0/bootsnap-1.4.5/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing bootsnap (1.4.5), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install bootsnap -v '1.4.5' --source
'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting error (exit code 2) for bootsnap, not allowing to set up Rails Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55386266/getting-error-exit-code-2-for-bootsnap-not-allowing-to-set-up-rails-server)

Comment: tried both solutions and it doesn't solve my issue

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Bootsnap won't work on Windows anyway, so I'd recommend just removing it from Gemfile. If you want to leave it for production environment, perhaps you should include it conditionally with something like:

```
gem 'bootsnap' unless (RbConfig::CONFIG['host_os'] =~ /mswin|mingw|cygwin/)
```